# Swapon for hibernation doesnt work

Tags: hibernate

Could someone help me with getting hibernate to work? I reinstalled my hard drive due to a corrupt update from Mate 16.04 to 17.10 making a shit ton of duplicate files on there, and now I can't get hibernation to work anymore.

Tried running sysctl hibernate in terminal, acts like normal shutdown (I think because of swapspace not being activated). My fstab shows something weird though, a cryptswap? I'll add a screenshot. Also I get an error after doing swapon, and I have no idea why it happens.

[image: partition scheme]

[image: fstabcontents]

[image: swapon error]

Did I screw something up?

Please do ask if you need more info.

Edit1: 
The hibernation guide on help.ubuntu.com states that you need use sudo systemctl hibernate, and as so this command made hibernation fail for me and act like a generic shutdown I thought I did something wrong, even though hibernation worked in the past. 
Yesterday I was tinkering with hibernation again (without the guide) and my memory made me use sudo pm-hibernate instead of what was given in the guide. 
Now that I'm sure I did not screw up, and using hibernation as usual again.

Sorry for the late edit but this question is solved.

The guide on help.ubuntu.com might need an update? Just a suggestion, I know that I don't know much about Linux, maybe this is just a fix for me and not for a lot of others.

Comment: When you run `free -h` what do you see?

Comment: Edited, sorry for late reaction. free -h gave me that swap partition should've worked properly though. The edited part explains further.